# Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow. DotNetNuke 4.5.1 Repository

Tags: dotnetnuke

I received this error "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow." when trying to upload any file in the Repository module of DotNetNuke.  I'm using dotnetnuke version 4.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of the file?  What version of the repository module are you using?

Otherwise, a few general recommendations....

1. Try to upgrade to the most current supported version of Repository and/or DotNetNuke.  There are many security and performance related fixes in the versions between 4.5.1 and 4.9.0 (The most current).
2. You might also post over on DotNetNuke.com as I am not sure how many DotNetNuke people really frequent this site, I haven't gotten much response in my attempts to get DNN discussions going here.